# postgresql csv file import

Tags: postgresql, csv

When I try to load a csv file into postgresql. I use the following command.

```
CREATE TABLE population(
    country char(80),
    year integer,
    population integer
);

COPY population FROM '/Users/chittampalliyashaswini/Desktop/population.csv'
           DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

Then I get the following error.

> ERROR:  could not open file "/Users/chittampalliyashaswini/Desktop/population.csv" for reading: Permission denied

Comment: No permissions to read from a file. The error seems pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: The error is pretty straight foward. The postgres user does not have access to the file you tryied to read. What else you need to know?

Comment: use psql and \Copy instead

Comment: country year population
Afghanistan 1995 17586073
Algeria 1995 29315463
Angola 1995 12104952
Argentina 1995 34833168
Azerbaijan 1995 7770806
Bangladesh 1995 119869585
Belarus 1995 10189075
Benin 1995 5985658
Bolivia (Plurinational State of) 1995 7635362
Botswana 1995 1583453
Brazil 1995 161890816
Burkina Faso 1995 10089876
Burundi 1995 6209923
Cambodia 1995 10769198
Cameroon 1995 13929575
Central African Republic 1995 3275695
Chad 1995 6980351
Chile 1995 14440103
China 1995 1237531429
China, Hong Kong SAR 1995 6144498
Colombia 1995 36573895
Congo 1995 2720633

Comment: this is a sample of the file that i'm trying to import.

Comment: idk how to paste it in a formatted way.

Answer (score 0):

The message is clear, the user postgresql is running under has no permission to read the file.
You can move it to /tmp and/or fix the permissions on the path. I typically switch to the postgres user and run a less to check.

If it is a one time thing, I suggest you simply move it to /tmp/ and use that path.

Comment: Actually, from the path, I'm guessing you are on MacOS perhaps? Or is it some MacOS-like distro?

Comment: I am using MacOS X Yosemite

Comment: I do not understand how to move it to /tmp. I have never done it before.

Comment: And I don't even have a tmp folder.

Comment: Now I moved it to the documents folder and ran the same command and I am getting this error.

Comment: ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00
CONTEXT:  COPY population, line 1

Comment: please paste first 3 lines and last 3 lines of your csv

Comment: ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00 CONTEXT: COPY population, line 1

Comment: What do you mean by paste first 3 lines and last 3 lines of my csv?

Comment: country year population
Afghanistan 1995 17586073
Algeria 1995 29315463

Comment: Yemen 2013 24407381
Zambia 2013 14538640
Zimbabwe 2013 14149648

Comment: I actually want to import the entire csv file.

Comment: Yes, and to understand the issue I wanted to see a sample of the CSV. Please paste into the question so everyone can see, formatted.

Comment: Now I run the script again and it is giving me the first issue.